# Replace array of characters with another character in a text file?

Tags: text-editors

Is there any tool to replace some characters with another one but at once , i mean for example i have text file like this :

```
.>+&5+B0"0,9,04A?@"56/!3
```

Replace each of this character with another character, eg: `. = H` , `> = E` 
Is there any tool available so give it all characters in array and replace with another array of characters , i know ( wish ) i could do this with programming but wondering if there is any tool or technique within certain word processing software that can handle this kind of tricks ,

Comment: I'm curious about the "all at once" part - do all of the substitutions have to be made at once because you have things like `A = B` and `B = C`?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Darth Android no all characters are unique , A = B , C = D , * = A and so on

Comment: @Paul Linux Suse & Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is precisely the purpose of the program "tr".  Naturally, you have to be using an OS that supports it (Linux, Cygwin, etc.)

```
cat myfile | tr 'ABCDEFGHIJ' '1234567890'
```

Comment: does this really do the trick i have openSuse , does this replace `A = 1 , B = 2 , ....`

Answer (score 3):

With sed available on Linux / Unix / MacOSX and some RegExp magic, you can quickly do any kind of text substitutions, e.g.:

```
sed -r "s:\.:H:g;s:>:E:g" < INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Or `sed 'y/.>/HE/'`.

Comment: could u describe this code , i mean what will get replaced with what so i can figure it out , am i able to write this script as long as full alphabetic replacement !?

Comment: For sed 'y/.>/HE/', the code is in the form `sed 'y/{CHAR SET TO BE REPLACED}/{REPLACEMENT CHAR SET}/'`
That means for A=>1, B=>2, C=>3, the code needed is
`sed 'y/ABC/123/'`.